# Pattern for avoiding circular dependency

Tags: design-patterns, circular-dependency

i was searching for a while, but i guess there's no question where i can really find the answer to my problem.

I'm working on a text based RPG game in java and my map is splitted in several areas, saved in a database, because it's a too large amount of data to store it in the memory. There's always one area loaded which contains * fields. Each field can contain 0..* NPCs, Items, Props, ...

Now my problem is, that every time the player walks onto a field, all NPCs on this field (and maybe on its neighbours) should be visible, which makes it senceful to save the NPC references in the fields. On the other hand, NPCs should be able to move around quite free, what would be easier, if the NPCs would have references about on which field they are at the moment.

I read a lot about circular dependencies now and I'm pretty sure that's the ugliest way to solve this problem. What I'm thinking of at the moment is to store references for NPCs in each area and references for the fields in the NPCs. That would be a middle way and the only big issue would be to move NPCs from one to another area, but at least that doesn't happen that often.

Now what I'm asking for is some kind of pattern to solve this problem or simply a good idea that leads me into the right direction. I'd be glad if anyone could help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but hopefull somebody else may need this opinion.

What I have seen often is to move the circular dependency far from each other, so that they are not directly aware or impacted. One way to do this would be to introduce a middle-man, which would keep references of both.
In object oriented programming, it would be to use interfaces and have both the dependent classes implement and use the interface.

The better option as stated by the design gurus, change your design so as to not end up in this situation (easier said ...)
Hope this helps

> V

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a database to store everything, it's probably better to have a reference to their location in each item/NPC/etc (null for no location) and query by that rather than store a list in each location.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I'd like to load the whole area where the player is in into the memory to avoid performance issues. I guess if I make a query every time the player moves and also want to find out the NPCs on the fields around the player's location this will require much time. I wonder if there isn't a better alternative.